# Unable to load -landroid jni

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am unable to load -landroid lib in my package, I am using following Android.mk 
code

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ShirtsAR

TARGET_PLATFORM := android-5

USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 := false

ifeq ($(USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1), true)
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv1_CM
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_1_1
else
    OPENGLES_LIB  := -lGLESv2
    OPENGLES_DEF  := -DUSE_OPENGL_ES_2_0
endif

ANDROID_LIB := -landroid 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ShirtsAR.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-write-strings $(OPENGLES_DEF)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog $(OPENGLES_LIB) $(ANDROID_LIB)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please guide, I am stuck.. :(

getting following error

```
/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -landroid
```

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libShirtsAR.so] Error 1

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Native Activity is only supported with API level 9 and higher (see docs/STABLE-APIS.html in your NDK distribution). So if you want to link against libandroid you'll need to change to

```
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-9
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use this APP_PLATFORM variable in the Application.mk file. I was able to build my solution after this.

Example:
APP_PLATFORM := android-22

Today October 2017 TARGET_PLATFORM doesn't work for me.

Cheers.